# jQuery No Conflict Still Conflicts with Other Version of jQuery 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have used this two jQuery in my site but jquery.min.js is conflict to jquery.js two are required.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please help me and provide solution

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask questions on this page, and try again/edit your question. We cannot help you if you don't supply us with information as to how your current code looks, what you have tried etc.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: You shouldn't use two versions of jQuery—and why use the unminified version anyway?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1**:

`jQuery.noConflict(true)` can be used but it  removes all jQuery variables exist in the global scope.

---

I can show you an example of using multiple jQuery files in the same page.

Note: I am adding this only because an answer stated other wise.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $j162 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1-11-1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j11 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Doing this one thing to be kept in mind is that you need to use `$j162` and `$j11` as alias name for which ever jQuery versions `1.6.2` and `1.11.1` you need to use respectively.

In my pages I need to use this because there are latest and outdated plugins in my page each need different jQuery versions.

And I have **Prototype JavaScript framework** in the page which also uses $ as an alias.

Comment: Jquery.js and jquery.min.js both are jquery library and both are required my website. Jquery.min.js it's working in bootstrap responsive and jquery.js  it's working in  multiple selection and ajax working but i have both simultaneously used at that time mutliple selection is not working it's stop by jquery.min.js and i have this remove jquery all the functionality are running.

Answer (score -2):

You can not use two jQuery versions at once.

The documentation for the jQuery.oConflict method states:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them.

Comment: No, you can use multiple version of jQuery at the same time. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: both are library jquery.min.js and jquery.js is working properly but jquery.min.js is stop the multiple checkbox functionality and i have remove this library at that time it's working properly and both library are required on our project.